# Anyone have experience with devise_invitable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can you add the ability to use devise_invitable in the controller. I wan to add additional fields like message, proeject_id along with the invitation but have no idea where to start?

Here's devise_invitable: [link text](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devise_inevitable engine defines two view files and one controller.  You more than likely do not need to perform any modifications to the controller that it defines.  The form that sends invitations to users is defined [here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/views/devise/invitations/new.html.erb) and you would override the rendering of the view like so:

```
#app/views/invitations/new.html.erb
<% form_for resource_name, resource, :url=> invitation_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
  <!-- Totally sweet new user invitation code goes here -->
<% end %>
```

The form that contains the code for users to complete registration after clicking the link on their email is [here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/views/devise/invitations/edit.html.erb) and you would override the rendering of it like so:

```
#app/views/invitations/edit.html.erb
<% form_for resource_name, resource, :url=> invitation_path(resource_name), :html=>{:method => :put } do |f| %>
  <!-- Totally sweet new user registration information goes here. -->
<% end %>
```

The first view is what will actually create the resource object, so that is more than likely where you'll want to be setting a message for the user to see, what project they are invited to as well.  You might also want to override [app/views/devise_mailer/invitation.html.erb](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/invitation.html.erb) to change the email message the user receives.

In order to override the [invitations controller](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb) you'd need to do this:

```
#app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb
class Devise::InvitationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    #totally rad create stuff here.
  end
end
```

Devise and its extensions are all Rails engines, so the request will first look for an appropriate controller/model/view/helper file in your app directory, then in vendor/gems, and then finally in the gem directory that defines the engine.

Comment: Thanks Patrick this is very helpful but where I'm stuck, is can I override the Invitable controller? I want to do something like this:   def create
    self.resource = resource_class.invite!(params[resource_name])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      #set_flash_message :notice, :send_instructions
      render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');"
    end

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a modal dialog that allows users to invite other users and add a message. I want the DEF CREATE controller to respond back with JS, so I can update the dialog, but I can't get it working. Ideas?

Comment: I threw in information about overriding the controller in the answer above.  Keep in mind this could harm your ability to upgrade this gem in the future.  Make sure to document what you've done.