# rails gem Devise Invitable accept view issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, invitation

I would like to have access to the user information in the invitation/accept route.  When I go to the form and use

```
<%= resource.name %>
```

it won't display the User.  It also appears that it isn't loading the user during the accept.  Is there an easy way to show the user some information about the invite?

Comment: I have no idea what "Devise Invitable" could possibly mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. You could override the devise invitable controller, see:
   [Anyone have experience with devise_invitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128398/anyone-have-experience-with-devise-invitable)
2. In my case, I wanted to pass the name of the invitor.

   - I add an integer attribute 'invitor' to the User class. This is the id of the invitor Person. Don't forget to add 'invitor' as attr_accessible in the model.
   - I already had a 'name' string attribute in the User class.
   - In the app/views/{users|devise}/invitations/new.html.erb (path may vary depending on how you generated the views) add a hidden form field with the logged in user (invitor):

   ... <%= f.text_field :invitor, :value => current_user.id, :hidden => true %> ...

   - In the email text app/views/{users|devise}/mailer/invitation.html.erb I can refer to the invitor:

   ... <%= (User.find @resource.invitor).name %> has invited you to <%= root_url %>, you can accept it through the link below....

Not that elegant, but it works. Improvements that survive updates of the devise_invitable gem are welcome.